# JS Form Fill Gets Vanished

Tags: javascript, forms

There are some forms that doesn't take values from JS function.

I have created a method to fill all the  fields, and when I click Continue button then all the filled information get vanished and error on every previously filled fields is showing "Please enter the * value".

Can anyone please help me with this?

Here is the sample link and code of the form that I need to fill:

https://applynow.capitalone.com/?productId=3429

```
function capitalone(){
 var data = {"firstName":"john","middleName":"","lastName":"smith","uSuffix":"","address":"5201 Great America Pakwy","address2":"","unit":"5201","city":"Santa Clara","state":"CA","zip":"95054","housing":"","Mortage":"","annual":"","position":"","employer":"","phone":"","email":"","DOB":"","securityNumber":"","motherMaidenName":"","account":"","amount":"","PAN":"","amexCardNo1a":"","amexCardNo1b":"","amexCardNo1c":"","phonePincode":"","compAddr1":"","employmentStatus":"","businessName":"hello","nameOnCard":"hello","legalStructure":"hello","TIN":"219312031","Ownership":"Publicly Traded","industryType":"Agriculture, Forestry, Fishing and Hunting","subcategory":"Forestry and Logging","industrySpeciality":"Logging","revenue":"100000","spendPerMonth":"1000"};
setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('legalBusinessName').focus()
    },500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#legalBusinessName')[0].value = data.businessName
    },1000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('businessNameOnCard').focus()
    },1500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#businessNameOnCard')[0].value = data.nameOnCard
    },2000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('combinedBusinessStreetAddress').focus()
    },2500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#combinedBusinessStreetAddress')[0].value = data.address
    },3000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('businessPhoneNumber').focus()
    },3500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#businessPhoneNumber')[0].value = data.phoneNumber
    },4000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('#businessLegalStructure_input .rw-dropdown-list-input').focus()
    },4500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#businessLegalStructure_input .rw-dropdown-list-input')[0].value = data.legalStructure
    },5000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('businessTIN').focus()
    },5500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#businessTIN')[0].value = data.TIN
    },6000)

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('#businessOwnershipType_input .rw-dropdown-list-input').focus()
    },6500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#businessOwnershipType_input .rw-dropdown-list-input')[0].value = data.Ownership
    },7000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('industryTypeMain').focus()
    },7500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#industryTypeMain')[0].value = data.industryType
    },8000)

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('industryTypeSubCategory').focus()
    },8500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#industryTypeSubCategory')[0].value = data.subcategory
    },9000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('industryTypeSpecialty').focus()
    },9500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#industryTypeSpecialty')[0].value = data.industrySpeciality
    },10000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('businessRevenue').focus()
    },10500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#businessRevenue')[0].value = data.revenue
    },11000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('businessSpend').focus()
    },11500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#businessSpend')[0].value = data.spendPerMonth 
    },12000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('firstName').focus()
    },12500)
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#firstName')[0].value = data.firstName;    
    },13000)
    if(data.middleName && data.middleName != "")
    {
      setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById('middleInitial').focus()
      },13500)
      setTimeout(function(){
         $('#middleInitial')[0].value = data.middleName;  
      },14000)
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('lastName').focus()
    },14500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#lastName')[0].value = data.lastName;    
    },15000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('dateOfBirth').focus()
    },15500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#dateOfBirth')[0].value = data.DOB;
    },16000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('socialSecurityNumber').focus();
    },16500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#socialSecurityNumber')[0].value = data.securityNumber;
    },17000)
    /*
    if(data.citizenship && data.citizenship != ""){
        if (data.citizenship == "Yes")
            $('#citizenYes').click();
        else
            $('citizenNo').click();
    }

    if (data.otherCitizenship && data.otherCitizenship != ""){
        if (data.otherCitizenship == "Yes"){
            $('dualCitizenYes').click();
        }
        else{
            $('dualCitizenNo').click();
        }
    }
    */
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('combinedStreetAddress').focus()
    },17500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#combinedStreetAddress')[0].value = data.address;
    },18000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('email').focus()
    },18500) 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#email')[0].value = data.email;
    },19000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('phoneNumber').focus()
    },19500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#phoneNumber')[0].value = data.phone;    
    },20000)

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('#checkingOrSavings_input .rw-dropdown-list-input').focus()
    },20500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelectorAll('#checkingOrSavings_input .rw-dropdown-list-input')[0].textContent = "Neither"
    },21000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('#employmentStatus_input .rw-dropdown-list-input').focus()
    },21500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelectorAll('#employmentStatus_input .rw-dropdown-list-input')[0].textContent = "Employed"
    },22000)

    if(data.Employed == "Employed")
    {
      setTimeout(function(){
          document.getElementById('occupation').focus()
      },22500)
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#occupation')[0].value = data.occupation;  
      },23000)
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('annualIncome').focus()
    },23500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#annualIncome')[0].value = data.annual;
    },24000)
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('monthlyRentMortgage').focus();
    },24500)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#monthlyRentMortgage')[0].value = data.Mortage;
    },25000)

}
```

Comment: post your code and we might be able to help you!

Comment: I have added code in the question

Comment: @Fuzzybear Could you please help me in this